# I have a weird html and css structure, how can I make my chat messages align to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, display

I'm working on a chat app for my assignment and I am almost done but I can't seem to get the text in the chat box to align at the bottom. I've tried `vertical-align:bottom` and `display:table-cell` and `display:block` but to no avail.

Html

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- title of app -->
        <div id = "title">
            <h2>SENG 513 Chat</h2>
        </div>

        <!--username-->
        <div id="usernameIndicator">
        </div>

        <div id ="currentOnline">   
                <p>Currently Online</p>
        </div>
        <!--chat messages and online users-->
        <div id ="main">

            <div id="messageArea">
                <ul id="messages"></ul>
            </div>

            <div id ="clear">
            </div>

            <div id ="usernames">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--chat and message bar-->
        <form action ="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, img {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;.
}

body{
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#3a6db7;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#title {
    /*background-color:#4286f4;*/
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

#usernameIndicator h2
{
    color:blue;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}

#currentOnline{
}

#main
{
    height:300px;
}

#messageArea{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#messages{

    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:table-cell;

}

#messages li {
    padding: 5px 10px;

}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #eee;
}

#usernames{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border: 1px solid;
    width:9%;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}

#messagebarArea{
    width:100%;
}
#form{
    width:100%;


}

form input { 
     width:90%;
     margin-top:20px;
     margin-bottom:20px;

}

form button {
    width: 9%; 
    background: rgb(130, 244, 255); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position to achieve what you needed. Assign Position Relative to the parent div #messageArea
Than Use position:absolute; with bottom:0; on #messages

```
#messageArea {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
}
    #messages {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Working Example
https://jsfiddle.net/z71dttg5/1/

You can read more about CSS Position by following the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks, it worked for text-align but there's a problem with chat message area. The scroll bar doesn't exist anymore when it overflows. I need the scroll bar.

Comment: Answer updated with link to CSS Positioning Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the container to be absolute, you can set it to align to the bottom.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("addMessage");
var list = document.getElementById("messages");
function addMessage() {
  var message = "test message";
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerHTML = message;
  list.appendChild(item);
  
  //Scroll Bottom
  list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight;
  
}
```

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, img {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;.
}

body{
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#3a6db7;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#title {
    /*background-color:#4286f4;*/
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

#usernameIndicator h2
{
    color:blue;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}

#currentOnline{
}

#main
{
    height:300px;
}

#messageArea{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}

#messages{
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    display:table-cell;

}

#messages li {
    padding: 5px 10px;

}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #eee;
}

#usernames{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border: 1px solid;
    width:9%;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}

#messagebarArea{
    width:100%;
}
#form{
    width:100%;


}

form input { 
     width:90%;
     margin-top:20px;
     margin-bottom:20px;

}

form button {
    width: 9%; 
    background: rgb(130, 244, 255); 

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- title of app -->
        <div id = "title">
            <h2>SENG 513 Chat</h2>
        </div>

        <!--username-->
        <div id="usernameIndicator">
        </div>

        <div id ="currentOnline">   
                <p>Currently Online</p>
        </div>
        <!--chat messages and online users-->
        <div id ="main">

            <div id="messageArea">
                <ul id="messages" tabindex="1">
               <li>test3</li>
                  <li>test3</li>
                  <li>test1</li>
                  <li>test2</li>
                  <li>test3</li>
                  <li>test1</li>
                  <li>test2</li>
                  <li>test3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id ="clear">
            </div>

            <div id ="usernames">
            </div>

        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="addMessage()" id="addMessage" value="add message"/>

        <!--chat and message bar-->
        <form action ="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, like user2111911's answer, it worked. Only problem is the scroll bar is gone when the messages overflow? I need that for my assignment. What is the problem? Is it the height:100% in #messageArea?

Comment: I updated the answer. Set #messages height to 100% and add overflow: auto; to #messages

Comment: Scrollbar is back but text isn't aligned to bottom anymore for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: My mistake. #messages should have max-height set to 100%.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue. One last thing, as new messages comes in and overflows, how I can make it stay scrolled to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

To make it fast and simple, just put your messages inside a regular table (it is not a mortal sin to use tables in HTML), it is not the best solution but it will get your assignment done.

If for some reason you can't use the `<table>` tag, then create the table with DIVs and CSS (display = table,table-cell, etc-)

```
<div id="messageArea">
<table style="height:100%; width:100%">
  <tr>
  <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
      <ul id="messages">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
      </ul>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```